# How to get neighbor lists in the same order/orientation from a periodic IGTriangularLattice[] graph?

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, code-request, order, igraphm

Using [IGraphM](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGDocumentation/#igtriangularlattice), I want to get the `VertexComponent[]` neighbors around all nodes, in a periodic `IGTriangularLattice[]` graph. To do that, I do:

```
(*Dimensions of the graph*)
i = 5;
j = 5;
(*Graph and neighborhoods distance {1} from each node*)
myPeriodicGraph = 
  IGTriangularLattice[{i, j}, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
   "Periodic" -> True,
   VertexCoordinates -> GraphEmbedding[IGTriangularLattice[{i, j}]]];
allNeighbors = 
  Table[VertexComponent[myPeriodicGraph, i, {1}], {i, 1, 
    VertexCount[myPeriodicGraph]}];
```

[image]

Now, just to visualize the order in which `VertexComponent[]` gives the neighborhoods, I have a list of colors to highlight these neighbors for any given focal cell:

```
colorNeighbors = {Red, Lighter[Red], Lighter[Lighter[Red]],
   Blue, Lighter[Blue], Lighter[Lighter[Blue]]}
```

[image]

Okay, let's see one particular neighborhood:

```
focalNode = 13;
GraphPlot[myPeriodicGraph, 
 VertexStyle -> (Rule[#[[2]], #[[1]]] & /@ 
    Transpose[{colorNeighbors, allNeighbors[[focalNode]]}])]
```

[image]

You can see that the `Red[]` tones are these neighbors to the "right" of the `focalNode`, and the `Blue[]` tones are these to the left. But this is not always the case! Especially when we query one of the nodes sitting at the "edges" of the graph (edge in spatial coordinates; topologically this is a "periodic" space).

```
focalNode = 23;
GraphPlot[myPeriodicGraph, 
 VertexStyle -> (Rule[#[[2]], #[[1]]] & /@ 
    Transpose[{colorNeighbors, allNeighbors[[focalNode]]}])]
```

[image]

You can see that the colors are now "disorganized". The same if you query other boundary nodes, and they disorganize in different ways:
[image]

So, my question is, can I get the neighborhoods in a way that they are always oriented in the same order? Let's say I have a canonical ordering: `{W, NW, NE, E, SE, SW}`, can I always get this order, no matter where the queried `focalNode` is? (below an example from a 'central' node, a node on the edge of the graph should preserve the orientation of the list of neighbors).
[image]

Thanks!

**Note**: It would be great if this could be extended to `IGSquareLattice[]`.

Comment: It sounds like you want a combinatorial embedding of these graphs for the torus? I think you will need to do some manual work in this case ...

Comment: @Szabolcs What's combinatorial embedding? (in simple terms XD). And yeah, I'm thinking right now on figuring out what is the order of neighbors given in the 'edge' nodes, and then just reordering them to the desired canonical order. But I'm hoping there's a simpler solution without having to check if all special cases would work. I don't want a torus, I actually want them on a plane as they are now (doing some spatial calculations that would be lost in the torus).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. We can use [`AdjacencyList[g,v]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AdjacencyList.html) to find the neighbors of a vertex `v` in graph `g`.
2. Construct a subgraph of `g` formed by neighbors of the focal node.
3. Then we can use [`FindHamiltonianPath`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindHamiltonianPath.html) on the subgraph starting with the *east* neighbor and ending with  the *south-east* neighbor of the focal node to get the neighbors in desired order.
4. Use the desired list of colors and ordered list of neighbors to construct a vertex styling rule.

```
Needs["IGraphM`"]

ClearAll[periodicGraph, ENeighbor, SENeighbor, orderedNeighborList, vertexStyle]

periodicGraph[{rows_, columns_}, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 IGTriangularLattice[{rows, columns}, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
  "Periodic" -> True, opts, VertexCoordinates -> 
   GraphEmbedding[IGTriangularLattice[{rows, columns}]]]

ENeighbor[{rows_, columns_}, v_] := Mod[v + rows, rows columns, 1]

SENeighbor[{rows_, columns_}, v_] := Module[{g = periodicGraph[{rows, columns}]}, 
  First @ DeleteCases[Mod[v + 1, rows columns, 1] | 
      Mod[ENeighbor[{rows, columns}, v] + 1, rows columns, 1]]@
    AdjacencyList[Subgraph[g, AdjacencyList[g, v]], ENeighbor[{rows, columns}, v]]]

orderedNeighborList[{rows_, columns_}, v_] := 
 Module[{g = periodicGraph[{rows, columns}]}, 
  RotateRight @ FindHamiltonianPath[Subgraph[g, AdjacencyList[g, v]], 
    ENeighbor[{rows, columns}, v], SENeighbor[{rows, columns}, v]]]

eSF = If[ChessboardDistance @@ #[[{1, -1}]] > 1, 
    GraphElementData["CurvedArc"][##], GraphElementData["Line"][##]] &;

colorNeighbors = {Red, Lighter[Red], Lighter[Lighter[Red]], Blue, 
   Lighter[Blue], Lighter[Lighter[Blue]]};

vertexStyle[{rows_, columns_}, v_] := Join[{_ -> White, v -> Green}, 
  MapThread[Rule, {orderedNeighborList[{rows, columns}, v], colorNeighbors}]]
```

***Examples:***

```
periodicGraph[{5, 5}, EdgeShapeFunction -> eSF, VertexStyle -> vertexStyle[{5, 5}, 13]]
```

[image]

```
periodicGraph[{5, 5}, EdgeShapeFunction -> eSF, VertexStyle -> vertexStyle[{5, 5}, 3]]
```

[image]

```
periodicGraph[{5, 5}, EdgeShapeFunction -> eSF, VertexStyle -> vertexStyle[{5, 5}, 23]]
```

[image]

```
periodicGraph[{5, 5}, EdgeShapeFunction -> eSF, VertexStyle -> vertexStyle[{5, 5}, 24]]
```

[image]

```
periodicGraph[{5, 5}, EdgeShapeFunction -> eSF, VertexStyle -> vertexStyle[{5, 5}, 20]]
```

[image]

```
periodicGraph[{5, 5}, EdgeShapeFunction -> eSF, VertexStyle -> vertexStyle[{5, 5}, 11]]
```

[image]

```
periodicGraph[{6, 4}, EdgeShapeFunction -> eSF, VertexStyle -> vertexStyle[{6, 4}, 2]]
```

[image]

```
Multicolumn[With[{i = 5, j = 5, v = #}, 
    Subgraph[periodicGraph[{i, j}], 
     Prepend[v]@RotateLeft@orderedNeighborList[{i, j}, v], 
     VertexLabels -> "Name", ImageSize -> Medium, 
     VertexLabelStyle -> 16,
     VertexStyle -> vertexStyle[{i, j}, v]]] & /@ 
   {13, 3, 23, 24, 20, 11}, 3]
```

[image]

```
Multicolumn[With[{i = 5, j = 5, v = #}, 
    Subgraph[periodicGraph[{i, j}], 
     Prepend[v]@RotateLeft@orderedNeighborList[{i, j}, v], 
     VertexLabels -> "Name", VertexLabelStyle -> 16, 
     ImageSize -> Medium, 
     VertexStyle -> vertexStyle[{i, j}, v]]] & /@ 
   {5, 10, 15, 20, 25}, 3, Appearance -> "Horizontal"]
```

[image]